# Unexplained wifi speeds on a TD-W9970 router, 802.11n, 40MHz Channel Width, 2.4GHz, with a Samsung Galaxy S9 and a Dell XPS 9560

Tags: wireless-networking, laptop, wireless-router, 802.11n, smartphone

My TD-W9970 modem/router is set in Wireless Mode. It has no cables connected to it, besides the power cable. I have it's Wifi card on, and I have connected 2 wireless clients to it, nothing else:

- A Samsung Galaxy S9 (SM-G960F Model), with (allegedly) a wifi chipset that supports 802.11 a/b/g/n/ac + MIMO (2.4Ghz, 5Ghz)
- A Dell XPS 9560 Laptop, with a Killer Wireless-n/a/ac 1535b Wireless Network Adapter

I set my TD-W9970 router to operate in 802.11n mode only, on the 13th Channel, with 40MHz Channel Width. It has SGI enabled. The status page of the router says it's operation speed is now 300Mbps (it drops to 144Mbps with different settings for example). I have no security right now on the Wifi Network, it is plain open. The TD-W9970 can only operate in 2.4GHz. Here are the screenshots from the configuration of the router:

**Status page**
[image]

**Basic Wireless Settings page**

[image]

**Advanced Wireless Settings page**

[image]

I am now sitting literally next to the TD-W9970, with the laptop on my lap and the phone in my hand or beside me. The 3 devices are all next to each other and I am in a big open room with no walls in between.

1. My S9 phone reports the link speed to be 144Mbps, first of all in the wifi settings:

[image]

Why is that. What little detail am I missing, that has a result to lose 50% nominal speed.
Additionally, the link speed is displayed as 117-130Mbps on [this application](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pzolee.android.localwifispeedtester&hl=el) downloaded from Google Play Store today, as it can be seen on the screenshots below. Moreover, when I run the "Wifi Test" in the application, I get 86.18Mbps "real" speed (I've gotten 106Mbps a couple of times, being in the same physical spot):

**WiFi Speed Test, WiFi Test**

[image]

Now the test that I care about is the actual transfer of files between the Laptop and the S9 Phone. So I did the SMB Test of the app and got this terrible result:

**WiFi Speed Test, SMBv2 Test**
[image]

Why am I getting the 8.3% of the TD-W9970 nominal wifi speed?

2. The Killer Wireless-n/a/ac 1535b Wireless Network Adapter shows the link as 300Mbps, in the settings page of its "Control Center" application:

**Killer Wireless Control Center, Settings**

[image]

So lastly, why does the Killer Wireless adapter detect the link as 300Mbps and the S9 as 144Mbps?

I have not done a WiFi test from the laptop to the phone, I don't know if there is a way, can't figure of one.

Comment: Sounds like you bought the lies + WIFI can not get the claimed speeds in any real world setup. Even if you are close to the router there is still interference from other sources (like other WIFI devices on same/overlapping channels, broadband noise etc). There is also huge variability in WiFi chipsets and sensitivity, arials etc. - With respect of SMB, problem is likely the protocol which is not particularly efficient. Try multiple simultaneous downloads and see how the aggregate perform.

Comment: I bought it as an emergency solution from a local shop, because the ISP's died. That was long ago, i am now trying to use it as a WiFi AP, but i'm so suprised about the WiFi performance. If i did not use SMB, how can I transfer files in my Network? FTP?

Comment: Do you have another device acting as an AP, like an ISP router?  How have you configured them to interplay?  There is no single solution to file sharing over a LAN, but SMB is probbably the most ubiquitous.   Depending on the kind of traffic I might be inclined to set up a web server (or even a full blown Nextcloud server).  My home file server offers files via SSH (SCP), DLNA (useful for sharing media files, but unidirectional) and SMB.    You may also want to investigate NFS - another horrible, but at least efficient protocol designed for file sharing.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/907108/why-is-samba-smb-slower-than-http-nfs-ftp-transfer-on-nas-on-my-lan#1241716 is worth a read as well